# (L&L vol. 4, sec. 59) Matrix Elements of the Electromagnetic Interaction Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, perturbation-theory, matrix-elements

In Sec. 59 ('The Scattering Tensor') of the fourth Landau and Lifshitz gives the matrix elements of the electromagnetic interaction operator  $\hat{V}=-\hat{\boldsymbol{d}} \cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{E}}$ as
$$ V_{n1} = -i\sqrt{2\pi \omega} (\boldsymbol{e}\cdot\boldsymbol{d}_{n1}), $$
given that the photon wavefunction is
$$\boldsymbol{A}_{\boldsymbol{e}\omega} = \sqrt{4\pi} \frac{\boldsymbol{e}}{\sqrt{2\omega}} e^{-i\omega t},$$
where $\boldsymbol{e}$ is the photon polarization (complex vector), $\boldsymbol{d}_{n1}$ is the matrix element (between states $n$ and 1 of the atom) of the dipole moment operator and $\hat{\boldsymbol{E}}=-\hat{\dot{\boldsymbol{A}}}$.

My question is how does the $e^{-i\omega t}$ dependence disappear when going from $\hat{\boldsymbol{V}}$ to $V_{n1}$?